# let ${v_1}, {v_2} $ be orthonormal basis for subspace $W$. Prove that if $z$ is a vector in $W$, then

Tags: linear-algebra

let ${v_1}, {v_2} $ be an orthonormal basis for a subspace $W$. Prove that if $z$ is a vector in $W$, then $||z||^2 = (z \cdot {v_1})^2 + (z \cdot {v_2})^2$

I'm not too sure where to start on this one. I'm thinking I have to cancel out ${v_1}$ and ${v_2}$ since the dot product of two orthogonal vectors is zero. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=\alpha v_1+\beta v_2$.  Then

- $\|z\|^2=z\cdot z=(\alpha v_1+\beta v_2)\cdot(\alpha v_1+\beta v_2)=\cdots=\alpha^2+\beta^2$;
- $z\cdot v_1=(\alpha v_1+\beta v_2)\cdot v_1=\cdots=\alpha$;
- $z\cdot v_2=\cdots=\beta$.

See if you can finish the proof by filling in the calculations where I have left dots.